# BigQuery billing changes based on unpartitioned/unclustered columns

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table which is partitioned by `ts` field (TIMESTAMP) and clustered by a `tag` field (STRING). It also has some other fields: `speed` (FLOAT) and `name` (STRING)

- When I perform `SELECT * from table1` it predicts full-table billing as expected
- When I perform `SELECT * from table1 WHERE ts='xxxxx'` it predicts partitioned billing as expected
- When I perform `SELECT * from table1 WHERE tag='yyy'`, it predicts less-than full-table billing (around 50% in my case). Post-query "bytes billed" is the same as the prediction. I was expecting post-query billing to differ from the pre-query prediction.
- When I perform `SELECT * from table1 WHERE name='zzz'`, it ALSO predicts less-than full-table billing (about 1% in my case), and again, post-query "bytes billed" is identical to the prediction. I was expecting full-table billing since I'm not even using a clustered field as filter
- When I perform `SELECT * from table1 WHERE speed=5`, it predicts full-table billing and post-query billed the same. Both `speed` and `name` are unclustered, yet `name` filtering reduces billing while `speed` does not. I was expecting similar behavior for both fields.
- When I perform `DELETE from table1 where tag='xxx'`, I get full-table billing as well. I was expecting cluster billing only.

Any idea what's going on? Seems like in most cases, my expectations aren't met so I'm probably missing something..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between partitioning and clustering is that partitioning divides the table into segments while clustering sorts the data into blocks.
When you add your where condition on the partitioned table you get a correct estimated billing because it prunes the table (basically looking at data in that segment). With clustering, however, your BQ does not know before running the query how many blocks it will scan so the estimation may not be accurate. In this case for example you will have multiple segments based on `ts` (partition) and in each block you will have blocks of the clustering.

- When I perform `SELECT * from table1` it predicts full-table
  billing as expected

This is because you have not specified for BQ to scan a particular segment in the table so it will scan the whole table. One thing you can do is force the requirement of a where condition on the partitioned column.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
  projectId.dataset.table 
PARTITION BY
  TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(timestamp, DAY)
  OPTIONS( require_partition_filter=TRUE )
```

- When I perform `SELECT * from table1 WHERE ts='xxxxx'` it predicts
  partitioned billing as expected

This is because you have specified for BQ to scan a particular segment and not the entire table.

- When I perform DELETE from table1 where tag='xxx', I get full-table
  billing as well. I was expecting cluster billing only.

when you perform a DELETE operation on a table, it typically results in full-table billing because BQ needs to scan the entire table to identify the rows that match the DELETE condition, and then it needs to rewrite the entire table without those rows.

- When I perform `SELECT * from table1 WHERE tag='yyy'`, it
  predicts less-than-full-table billing (around 50% in my case).
  Post-query "bytes billed" is the same as the prediction. I was
  expecting post-query billing to differ from the pre-query prediction.

The clustering reduces the cost. The documentation says with clustering you may not get an accurate estimate but BQ tries to scan only relevant portions so it can be accurate sometimes.

- When I perform `SELECT * from table1 WHERE name='zzz'`, it ALSO
  predicts less-than-full-table billing (about 1% in my case), and
  again, post-query "bytes billed" is identical to the prediction. I
  was expecting full-table billing since I'm not even using a clustered
  field as filter

BQ has other ways that optimise performance, for example, Caching. if you run a similar query, BigQuery might use cached results to reduce the amount of data scanned, which might have not been the case when you filter by speed.

### Difference between select and delete

Select will simply filter and write the results as the output. [image: execution graph for select]

Delete has many more operations hence scans the entire dataset. You will see on the execution details the following steps:

S00: Input
Reads and filters input data from the table based on the `where` condition.
Hashes filtered records for subsequent processing.

S01: Sort+
Sorts the filtered output from the previous stage.
Assigns a new value `REINSERT` to a temp column in the sorted records. On this stage, it reads both the initial data and the filtered data.

S02: Coalesce
Prepares the sorted data for final output, potentially consolidating or organizing it. e.g partitioning and clustering

S03: Output
Writes the processed data to the final output destination, selecting specific columns for the output.
[image: Execution details for delete]

Comment: Thanks, can you clarify while DELETE and SELECT behave differently, using the exact same clustered filter?

Comment: @SagiMann 
The difference is in how the delete and the select function works. When you delete it involves reading the data, filtering based on a condition, sorting, and then writing the output to a temporary stage. I`m adding a detail explanation on my answer.